# how to add error message to try again if fgets is larger than specified without the program automatically closing on me

Tags: arrays, c, fgets

I am trying to make a program that gets user input for a username in an array of characters and is able to call any letter from the array but if I enter more than 20 characters or none at all how do I add an error message like "Try again" without the program automatically closing when I enter too many or stopping if I enter none at all pressing just enter?

```
int main(void)
{
    char name[20];
        
    
    printf(": ");
    fgets (name, 20, stdin);

    printf("%c", name[2]);

}
```

Comment: Check the result of `name`. `strlen` can be used to tell you if the entered value is empty or can also check if first character is a newline which also means it was empty. And if it does not end with a newline character then it means it was too long.

Comment: im really new to this can you specify a little more? possibly an example for me?

Comment: `if (name[0] == '\n')` tells you a blank response was entered. `if (name[strlen(name) - 1] != '\n')` tells you that `fgets` could not store the whole string and hence it was too long. Should also check the return value of `fgets` in case there is any other error.

Comment: yes it worked! thank you kaylum much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The program automatically closes because you reach the end of `main` routine.

The behaviour of `fgets` when you don't provide enough buffer to hold the full string is to fill it as much as possible (and this is the full buffer size, less one char to put the final string terminator), put the last `'\0'` to end the string, and return what you have.  The rest of the line will be returned in the next `fgets` (again, if it fills completely, or you will need another read to handle it)

Had you  checked the returned value of `fgets` you would see that it returned a normal string and the return value was `!= NULL`.

The way to detect that you got more characters than requested is to search for the last character of the returned string to be a `'\n'` character.  If it is, then the read ended at the line terminator.  If it is not, then the buffer is full, and it filled it completely (but be careful, that the last char of the buffer will be a `'\0'`, I'm talking about the previous to last)

If you just press `<ENTER>` you'll get one character (not none), the `'\n'` itself.  The only way to get a `NULL` return value from `fgets` is to have no more input at all (and end of file condition) which, from the terminal, can be issued by pressing Ctrl-D at the beginning of the line.